# Append content to div smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website loads "sub-pages" after choosing from a menu and appends it to a empty hidden div.

It's working, but I'm not satisfied with the feeling of it. The website kind of stutters/blinks when swapping the content of the div.

So, what I'm doing is like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="button" id="page1">Button for link</div>
<div class="subContent">
    <div class="containerContentBox textLeft">                  
        <div id="placeContent"><!-- Content goes here --></div>                 
    </div>
</div>
```

In the Javascript I'm trying to smooth out the transition by fading out the main div, change content and then fade it back in as shown below:

**JS**

```
var chosenPage = "";

// Click button
$('.button').click(function(){              
    chosenPage = $(this).attr('id');    
    $('#placeContent').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#placeContent').empty();
        showSelectedPage();
    });    
});

// Apply the page
function showSelectedPage(){        
    var newPageFile = "/pages/" + chosenPage + ".html";     
    $.get(newPageFile)
        .done(function(data) {          
            $('#placeContent').html(data);              
            $('#placeContent').fadeIn('fast', function(){
                scrollToContent();
            });
        }).fail(function() { 
            console.log('Page not found');
            return;
        });

}

// Scroll to top of the appended page   
function scrollToContent(){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".subContent").offset().top - 40
    }, 'slow');
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this ? I think the blinking/stutter comes from the scrollbar changing height.

Comment: jQuery feels like a dated approach to accomplish this. Are you trying to avoid using CSS? That would likely be much smoother...

Comment: Not avoiding CSS at all, only reason I haven't thought about doing it in CSS is that I don't know how to achieve this effect with it.

Comment: Okay, great. I would typically approach this by setting a `transition` property on opacity of the divs to fade in and out, then set `opacity` to zero, listen for the `transitionend` event and remove the old element. I can write a proper answer in a half hour or so if nobody else is faster :)

Comment: That'd be great. Thanks m8